# Trouble with a simple GoogleScript code (google sheets + gmail integration)

Tags: javascript, google-sheets-api

```
function checkReminder() {
  // get the spreadsheet object
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  // set the first sheet as active
  SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheets()[0]);
  // fetch this sheet
  var sheet = spreadsheet.getActiveSheet();

  // figure out what the last row is
  var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();

  // the rows are indexed starting at 1, and the first row
  // is the headers, so start with row 2
  var startRow = 2;

  // grab column 10 (the 'date end' column) 
  var range = sheet.getRange(2,10,lastRow-startRow+1,1 );
  var numRows = range.getNumRows();
  var date_end_values = range.getValues();

  // Now, grab the Event name data
  range = sheet.getRange(2, 5, lastRow-startRow+1, 1);
  var reminder_info_values = range.getValues();

  var warning_count = 0;
  var msg = "Send out a follow-up email asking how the event was!";

    }

//Get today's date
var todaysDate = new Date();
var numRows = numRows
// Loop over the days left values
for (var i = 0; i <= numRows - 1; i++) {
var date_end = date_end_values[i][0];

//call setHours to take the time out of the comparison
if(date_end == todaysDate.setHours(0,0,0,0)) {
MailApp.sendEmail("max@xpogo.com", 
"Reminder Spreadsheet Message", msg);
  }
```

What I'm trying to do is have gmail send me a reminder when a certain column in my data set is equal to the present date. Im new to coding and am running into trouble. Please help?

Answer (score 0):

I added the following after your variables were set, to determine whether they were commensurate for your comparison (hit ctrl+Enter after executing to view the log).

```
Logger.log(date_end);
Logger.log(todaysDate.setHours(0,0,0,0));
```

They weren't comparable at all. Here are the lines I changed to make this work:

```
var todaysDate = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT+1", "MM/dd/yyyy");

var date_end = Utilities.formatDate(date_end_values[i][0], "GMT+1", "MM/dd/yyyy");

if(date_end == todaysDate) {
```

HTH